# Sort by money mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, sorting

my class manager

```
public IQueryable<Products> SortProducts(int? GetPage, int? cat, string Sorter)
        {
            switch (Sorter)
            {
                case "date":
                    return SortOrderByPage(GetPage, cat).OrderBy(p => p.Date);
                case "price":
                    return SortOrderByPage(GetPage, cat).OrderBy(p => p.Price);
                default:
                    return SortOrderByPage(GetPage, cat).OrderBy(p => p.Id);
            }
        }
```

and result for CASE "price":

```
price1: 104566
price2: 123566
price3: 124566
```

What it?? please help me

Comment: is "price" by any chance a string? in that case, parse it to an int.

Comment: yes all price is string (but only numbers in field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you are seeing, is to be expected when you compare strings.

Anything starting with "1" should come before something starting with "2" just like "Apple" should come before "Banana".

Since you commented that your prices are stored as `string`s, you should parse it to an int before sorting. (Or even better: store it as an int!)

```
case "price":
    return SortOrderByPage(GetPage, cat).OrderBy(p => int.Parse(p.Price));
```

Comment: Expression LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method "Int32 Parse (System.String)",...  he;s dont know convert metgod !(

Comment: Then I would suggest that you change your system to store prices as `int`s instead. After all, this is the proper way to do it.

Comment: yes, i'm edited my DB, string to int (for price). And case "price":
                    return SortOrderByPage(GetPage, cat).OrderBy(p => p.Price); is correctly, Thk You!